# mysql count rows and group them by month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called cc_calls and there I have many call records I want to count them and group them in months I have a timestamp called starttime and I can use that row to extract the month, also limit the count for 12 months

the results should be like:

```
Month       Count

January     768768
February    876786
March       987979
April       765765
May         898797
June        876876
July        786575
August      765765
September   689787
October     765879
November    897989
December    876876
```

Can anyone guide me or show me the mysql query that I need to get this result.

Comment: I am sure there are duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
MONTH(starttime),
COUNT(*)
FROM cc_calls
GROUP BY MONTH(starttime)
```

Be aware though, that this counts for each month of **every** year. You might want to include the year in the `select` and `group by` clauses or filter for a specific year in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
MONTH(starttime),
COUNT(*)
FROM cc_calls
GROUP BY (MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(starttime)))
```